# Firebase sendPasswordResetEmail doesn't send email

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem concerning my application using firebase: If I want to enable the users to reset their password themselves firebase doesn't send an email to their address. If I do it myself from the firebase console it works fine. I'm trying it like this:

```
   resetPassword(email: string) {
        sendPasswordResetEmail(this.auth, email)
            .then(() => {
                // Password reset email sent!
                // ..
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                // ..
            });
    }
```

Has someone some insights for me, why this isn't working? I get my auth like this:

```
this.firebaseApp = initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);
this.auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
```

I am using the Firebase Modular SDK (V9.0.0+).

I would be really grateful if someone can help me!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting environment from? If you are getting it correctly and `environment.firebaseConfig` is not undefined then this should work.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, sendPasswordResetEmail } from "firebase/auth";

const app = initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
  .then(() => {
    // Password reset email sent!
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, it works now...I called my method containing the sendPasswortResetEmail() incorrectly... thanks though! :)

Comment: Would be really beneficial if you could add what you did as an answer, I am in the same position as you were.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for not providing the most useful answer, what I suggest is:

1. Verify the console is not throwing Firebase errors
2. Validate that the firebase env variables are correct

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering nonetheless. There are no errors in the console and the env variables are set correctly, since I just copied them out of the firebase console.